# Trouble retrieving data from REST endpoint using Angular -- URL keeps showing static/

Tags: angularjs, django, rest

I'm currently having an issue that has been driving me crazy for the past 30-40 mins. I've successfully created a products api using Django/Django REST framework. But when I call the endpoint to try and consume it with angular, I get a 404 error. When I open the console I am greeted with an error that states `GET http://localhost:8000/static/api/products/ 404 (Not Found)`. However, when I navigate to the URL manually in browser I get the browsable api menu.

I'm not exactly sure what's going on here...but I'm thinking it could be because of my angular static URLs/roots.

Here is the current code for the main area URLs of the app:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
        from django.contrib import admin

        from django.conf.urls.static import static
        from django.conf import settings

        urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
            url(r'^api/', include('customerreview_rest.urls', namespace='api')),
            url(r'^api/',include ('products_rest.urls', namespace='api')),
            url(r'^', include('GemStore_App.urls',namespace='frontend')),
        ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

    Here is the products URL/root for the endpoint:

        from django.conf.urls import url,include
    from rest_framework import routers
    from products_rest.viewsets import ProductsViewsets

    router = routers.DefaultRouter()
    router.register('products',ProductsViewsets,'products')


    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^', include(router.urls)) #base router
    ]
```

Lastly, here is the code for the static angular files:

```
    from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='static/index.html', permanent=False), name='index')
]
```

Here also, is the code I planed to use to consume the api using Angular:

```
    myStore.controller("myStoreController",function($scope,$http){
        $scope.gems = $http.get("api/products/").then(
            function(response){
                $scope.gems = response.data
            }, function(error){
                $scope.error = error
            });


})
```

Any light that can be shed on this topic, or maybe a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does `/products/` work?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't...now, it just strips the `/static/api/`and the way the API is set up, I need to include API inside of the call.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the issue was that I needed to include a another `/` in my call in order for it to be accepted.

So in summary, the code for the angular portian looks like this now:

```
myStore.controller("myStoreController",function($scope,$http){
        $scope.gems = $http.get("/api/products/").then(
            function(response){
                $scope.gems = response.data
            }, function(error){
                $scope.error = error
            });


})
```

@Sayse Thanks for helping.